# Get variable by text by group for apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I am trying to apply a scaling function to a data.frame, by a 'category' group. The scaling function requires a specific scalar depending on it's category. The calculation is: each value of 't' is divided by the total of 't' per 'cat', and then multiplied by the scalar that matches 'cat' (i.e. 'fac.a' for cat=a, etc.).

I use 'get' to call the specific scalar, but it is only using the value for the 1st line and applying to the whole data.frame:

```
# my scaling factors:
fac.a <- 15
fac.b <- 12
fac.c <- 20

# dummy data.frame
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(t = sample(1:100,15),cat = rep(c("a","b","c"),each=5))

# apply function that groups & sums the df$t values by df$cat, divides each df$t by its 
# repsective category total and applies the correct scalar with a get function.
df$scaled <- apply(df[1], 2, function(x) (df$t/ave(df$t, df$cat, FUN=sum))*get(paste0("fac.",df$cat)) )
```

Unfortunately I'm only getting the right answer for the 1st category as the get function is only calling the 1st scalar.

This can be done with relative ease in 4 to 5 lines (building separate attributes etc) but I'd like to achieve it in an apply function.

N.B. why is the new attribute called "t" in the data.frame but "scaled" when I examine names(df) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, newt := sum(t), cat][, 
   scaled := (t/newt) * get(paste0('fac.', cat)), 1:nrow(df)][, newt := NULL][]
#     t cat    scaled
# 1:  51   a 3.8059701
# 2:  31   a 2.3134328
# 3:  42   a 3.1343284
# 4:  68   a 5.0746269
# 5:   9   a 0.6716418
# 6:  22   b 1.1046025
# 7:  26   b 1.3054393
# 8:  94   b 4.7196653
# 9:  57   b 2.8619247
#10:  40   b 2.0083682
#11:  59   c 3.6875000
#12: 100   c 6.2500000
#13:  10   c 0.6250000
#14:  52   c 3.2500000
#15:  99   c 6.1875000
```

---

Or a faster option would be to create a key/value dataset, join with the original data to create the 'scaled' column

```
df2 <- setnames(setDT(stack(mget(ls(pattern="fac\\.")))[2:1]),
                      1, "cat")[, cat := sub(".*\\.", "", cat)][]
setDT(df)[df2, scaled := (t/sum(t))*values, on = .(cat), by = .EACHI]
df
#      t cat    scaled
# 1:  51   a 3.8059701
# 2:  31   a 2.3134328
# 3:  42   a 3.1343284
# 4:  68   a 5.0746269
# 5:   9   a 0.6716418
# 6:  22   b 1.1046025
# 7:  26   b 1.3054393
# 8:  94   b 4.7196653
# 9:  57   b 2.8619247
#10:  40   b 2.0083682
#11:  59   c 3.6875000
#12: 100   c 6.2500000
#13:  10   c 0.6250000
#14:  52   c 3.2500000
#15:  99   c 6.1875000
```

Comment: yep, I'm an avid user of data.table, love it. But i'm desperately trying to figure this out in apply using get. Perhaps i'm being stupid but it's the problem i'd like to solve! thanks for your answer though

Comment: @Sam I would say it is better not to use `apply` here as there is a single column and `apply` converts the output to `matrix`

Comment: ok thanks. Also, your scaled figures look a little low....the first scaled result should be about 3.8, for instance. I think you've divided by the scalar instead of multiplying, i'm betting that's my slightly poor question :)

Comment: @Sam I edited the code.  Is that wat you are looking for ?

Comment: yes cheers, i've updated the 1st paragraph of the qu too. I'll head back to data.table then, thanks for the answer. Apply abandoned once more!

Comment: @Sam You can use apply when it is looped through rows, but, this can be vectorized as in the 2nd solution